# NullPointer exception while trying to run a device on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to android studio. I am getting a Nullpointer exception while running a device on android studio. I am using armeabi-v7a sdk for arm processor. The error looks like this..

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidSessionInfo.isEmbeddable(AndroidSessionInfo.java:62)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getOldSessionTarget(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:307)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:279)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:201)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:58)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:53)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:94)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:396)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$400(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$5.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:332)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.de34.myfirstapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my gradle looks like :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.de34.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Main activity Node :

```
package com.example.de34.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void OnclickMe(View view){
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,"oh you clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.de34.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!click me if you dare"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clickMe"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: need some piece of code..It will be very helpfull

Comment: have updated my gradle and manifest files plz look into it

Comment: Are there any gradle build or lint errors? I'm reading this link http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?t=10848&p=31089

Comment: Please add MainActivity code, I believe that you missing to initial some variable

Comment: no there are no gradle build errors. @cricket_007

Comment: @user2235615 - I don't think so, the NPE is coming from Android Studio itself.

Comment: Is this a completely new project? What version of Android Studio?

Comment: Just to make sure, add your XML and Java code

Comment: Ok, add your XML file too please

Comment: where do you create R.id.toolbar and R.id.fab?

Comment: yes a completely new project and the version in 1.5.0 @cricket_007

Comment: i didn't create any those are by default as toolbar and fab @user2235615

Comment: Did you try to debug the project with break points?

Comment: I didn't see any toolbar and floatingActionButton in your xml

Comment: @pavansp Is that the whole error stack you've posted? You may need to scroll up sometimes to get to the start

Comment: Please continue chat here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102963/nullpointer-exception-while-trying-to-run-a-device-on-android-studio

Comment: yep tried everything got nothing there @user2235615

Comment: sorry @user2235615 i dont have enough reputations to chat in chat rooms.

Comment: those toolabar and floatinActionButton are present in main_activity.xml file @AsifSb

Comment: Can you join to the chat ?

Comment: @user2235615 i dont have enough reputation to join the chat room

Comment: Ohh OK, Look at this example http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/floating-action-button-fab-using-android-design-support-library.html and see if it work for you.

Comment: Try creating a completely new project and add only a blank activity. Add no code to it and try to run the emulator. Let me know if you can run that.

Comment: even if i go and run my virtual device its asking me to close the program some memory issues i guess

Comment: Just to add some info on this issue.  I get this exact stack trace in Android Studio 1.5 when I try to launch the debugger on device or emulator.  No problem if I run the app and I can attach the debugger to process. It happens immediately so the app has not been downloaded and is not running yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this exact stack trace only when I tried debugging my application (running it worked fine).  I was using Android Studio 1.5.  Restarting Android Studio I noticed this error:  “Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8601): java.net.ConnectException “Connection refused".  This lead me to realize I had another instance of Android Studio running.  When I closed the 2nd instance the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

you have to add ToolBar in layout file as give below

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

suppose this is your  **app_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

<TextView

            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="My App Bar"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```